# Obscure / grey-out an inactive button

Tags: c#, wpf, button, styles

I want to make a button behave such that, if I do not click on `dataGrid` items the button is inactive. The code below works, but how do I obscure the button (shaded / greyed out)?

```
<Button x:Name="btDel" Height="22" Width="22" Click="btDel_Click" IsEnabled="False"
        ToolTip="tooltip"
        >

    <Button.Content>
        <Image Source="PNGImages/ItemDel.png"></Image>
    </Button.Content>

    <Button.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                        Binding="{Binding ElementName=dgTable,Path=SelectedIndex}"
                        Value="-1">
                    <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>

</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your own style. This part ensures appearance of button when is disabled. `<VisualState x:Name="Disabled">`.

Default button style :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Usage :

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource _yourStyle}" 
    ......
<Button/>
```